# Facebook 0Auth Client login not working. PHP APP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have created a facebook app using PHP-SDK which posts a message on user's feed and it will print app access token on the canvas page. It does not opens any Dialog box for permissions access to app, also after opening the app it does not do anything. It just show "Please Login" where login isa button having some link which too isnot working. Help me!

```
<?php
// Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
// directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
require_once('src/facebook.php');

$config = array(
'appId' => 'myappidhere',
'secret' => 'mysecrete,
'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
?> 
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<?php
if($user_id) {

// We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
  // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
  try {
    $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                array(
                                  'link' => 'www.facebook.com',
                                  'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!Learning PHP     and Facebook API :D :D'
                             ));
    echo '<pre>Post ID: ' . $ret_obj['id'] . '</pre>';

$token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
echo 'test';
echo $token;

 // Give the user a logout link 
    echo '<br /><a href="' . $facebook->getLogoutUrl() . '">logout</a>';
  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
    // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
    // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
    // just ask the user to login again here.
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
                   'scope' => 'publish_stream'
                   )); 
    echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
} else {

  // No user, so print a link for the user to login
  // To post to a user's wall, we need publish_stream permission
  // We'll use the current URL as the redirect_uri, so we don't
  // need to specify it here.
  $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array( 'scope' => 'publish_stream' ) );
  echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';

}
```

?>

Is there any special settings which i have to do in my APP dashboard on facebook?

Answer (score 0):

You missing single quotes at:

```
'secret' => 'mysecrete',
```

Is this a typo only in this post, not in your code? And is any arrors displayed? Use var_dump for dumping url:

```
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl( array(
               'scope' => 'publish_stream'
               )); 
var_dump($login_url);
```